# terraform-destroy workflow github actions

Tags: terraform, github-actions

I was able to deploy ec2 instance with github actions workflow. any idea what i need to do to reverse or destroy the changes I deployed on aws?

Here is my terraform apply form

```
name: Terraform-Apply

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
      
jobs:
  terraform:
    name: "Terraform Apply"
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    env:
      AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
      AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
      AWS_REGION: 'us-west-1'
      
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
        
      - name: Setup Terraform                                                                      
        uses: hashicorp/setup-terraform@v1

      - name: Terraform Init
        id: init
        run: terraform init  

      - name: Terraform Plan
        id: plan
        if: github.event_name == 'push'
        run: terraform plan -no-color
        continue-on-error: true
        
      - name: Terraform Plan Status
        if: steps.plan.outcome == 'failure'
        run: exit 1
        
      - name: Terraform Apply
        if: github.ref == 'refs/heads/main' && github.event_name == 'push'
        run: terraform apply -auto-approve
```

Comment: Please show what you have tried and how that did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Since you aren't using any Terraform workspace, you can simply create a new TF_Destroy workspace with a workflow dispatch that can help you to execute it manually. This will nuke all the infrastructure.

```
name: Terraform Destroy
on:
 workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
 tf-destroy:
   runs-on: ubuntu-latest
   env:
      AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
      AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
      AWS_REGION: 'us-west-1'
   steps:
     - name: Terraform destroy
       id: destroy
       run: terraform destroy -auto-approved
```

There is no way you can recover the destroyed resources.

Comment: I tried but it says nothing to destroy

Comment: ``` name: Terraform Destroy
on:
 workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
 tf-destroy:
   runs-on: ubuntu-latest
   env:
      AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
      AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
      AWS_REGION: 'us-west-1'
   steps:
     - name: Terraform destroy
       id: destroy
       run: terraform destroy -auto-approve

Comment: That's because I haven't added the initialization steps like setup terraform, aws cli if needed, checking out the code. These are the default steps that needs to be included in any GitHub workflows.

Answer (score 0):

ok The following worked

```
name: Terraform Destroy
on:
 workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
 tf-destroy:
   runs-on: ubuntu-latest
   env:
      AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
      AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
      AWS_REGION: 'us-west-1'
   steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
        
      - name: Setup Terraform                                                                      
        uses: hashicorp/setup-terraform@v1

      - name: Terraform Init
        id: init
        run: terraform init  
        
      - name: Show Destroy plan
        run: terraform plan -destroy
        continue-on-error: true

      - name: Terraform destroy
        id: destroy
        run: terraform destroy -auto-approve
```

Thank you